# Rails Pushing parameter to another page after jquery generate it

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my Rails app:

**HTML:**

```
<li class="list-group-item">Total: <span id="total"></span></li>
```

**JS:**

```
total = (PRICE - disc1 - disc2 - disc3) * nDays + tourFee + 35;
$('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
```

I need to pass the #total value **via link** to another page after javascript generates this value, and then use it via params[]. How can I do it?

Comment: You want it in controller ?

Comment: How would you like to proceed this value to another page, while you saying another page it's consider as another action or another controller . so is there any form to be submitted to pass this total value to another page or via any link? explain it.

Comment: @Gabbar via rails link or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append it to link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Next page",next_page_path, class: 'next-link' %>

<script>
    const total = (PRICE - disc1 - disc2 - disc3) * nDays + tourFee + 35
    const $nextLink = $('.next-link')
    $nextLink.attr('href', $nextLink.attr('href') + "?param=" + total.toFixed(2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Via link

```
<%=link_to 'Submit', '#', id: 'submit_link'%>
```

Js

```
total = (PRICE - disc1 - disc2 - disc3) * nDays + tourFee + 35;
$('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
path_to_new_page = '/path_to_new_page?total=' + total
$('#submit_link').attr('href', path_to_new_page)
```

So at another page(or another action which is routed with '/path_to_new_page')

```
params[:total] = value of total which is sent via link
```